# Endpoint in Spring receive string null instead null value of an object

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

Hello I have a service in Angular whose take a variable string a send a endpoint in Spring:

[image]

Endpoint:
[image]

The case is that the sysout in yellow prints: "null". So the rest enpoint interpret that it is the string=null but a I need that  this be null like an object.

Cheers.

Comment: First of all, [you should not post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Second, you need to provide the implementation of `findByIdentitfication` method, because there's the place where you make the actual request. My hunch is that you use string coercion with `"" + identification` and that's why you get a string which contains `"null"`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this workaround:
[image]

And add to validation in the endpoint to proceed according when the value comes empty also.